# Inflating custom view in android

Tags: android, xml, android-view, classnotfoundexception, android-inflate

I have created a custom view that show an arc compeleting into a circle. My objective is to show the view in my xml. I am trying to inflate my custom view class in my xml but it is giving me error. My objective is to show it in my mainactivity in a framelayout. I am posting my code as well as the error report. Please have a look at it. And if there is any other approach for this please do let me know.
Thanks

```
    public class CusImage extends View {
    private Paint myPaint;
    private Paint myPaint2;
    private Paint myFramePaint;
    private RectF bigOval;
    public TextView value;
    private RectF bigOval2;
    private float myStart;
    private float mySweep;
    private float SWEEP_INC = 3;
    private float SWEEP_INC2 = 5;
    // Use this flag to control the direction of the arc's movement
    private boolean addToCircle = false;

    public CusImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            init();
        }
    }


    private void init() {
        myPaint = new Paint();

        myPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        bigOval = new RectF(40, 10, 280, 250);

        myFramePaint = new Paint();
        myFramePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        myFramePaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        canvas.drawRect(bigOval, myFramePaint);
        canvas.drawArc(bigOval, myStart, mySweep, false, myPaint);
        myStart = -90;

        mySweep += SWEEP_INC2;

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to inflate it in my xml:

```
<com.example.progressframework.MainActivity.CusImage
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 </com.example.progressframework.MainActivity.CusImage>
```

And below is the latest  error:

```
 Exception raised during rendering: loader 
 (instance of com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/resources/
 manager/ProjectClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name:     
  "com/example/progressframework/MainActivity$CusImage"
  Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

And Logcat:

```
    08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawRect(GLES20Canvas.java:1136)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at com.example.progressframework.CusImage.onDraw(CusImage.java:60)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13944)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)    
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2224)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-26 12:26:33.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you check that That class is in your com.example.progressframework.MainActivity package??

Comment: yes it is in the package. Actually I have created this class inside MainActivity class. When I set the contentview as CusImage class, it is fine. But i want this view to be in a xml.

Comment: It would be gud if you create a seperate class for cusImage. So it would be used by com.example.progressframework.cusImaage ignoring mainActivity.

Comment: I had tried that as well. But no luck.

Comment: can you create CusImage as a separate class file (.java) com.example.progressframework.CusImage. instead of subcalss ?

Comment: Can you remove those comments you put in for second constructor and try again to execute code..

Comment: I have moved the class to a seperate file. Now when i run the program it is giving me a different error. I have updated it in the question.

Comment: Now it is giving me null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

your class needs ctor with Context and AttributeSet params, also put it in a separate compilation unit

Comment: why if(isInEditMode()) ?

Comment: Ohk Thanks a lot. That solved the issu. The eclipse XML editor was suggesting me to use that. That is why i put that in my code. Now that I have removed it, the code is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your cusImage class.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    invalidate();
```

}

and remove invalidate() from onDraw method.